# 301 Redirect of Static HTML to Dynamic PHP Page

Tags: http-status-code-301

After upgrading our website, many old links that people have in blogs, etc. are now going to our 404 error page.

An example is: (using h#p b/c I'm a new user and can't post links)

```
h#p://www.site.com/pressreleases/some_release.html
h#p://www.site.com/pressreleases/another_release.html
```

These items are now part of a db-driven site and would be live here:

```
h#p://www.site.com/pressreleases/details.php?id=1
h#p://www.site.com/pressreleases/details.php?id=2
```

How can I set up the 301 to redirect
`h#p://www.site.com/pressreleases/some_release.html`
to
`h#p://www.site.com/pressreleases/details.php?id=1`,

and
`h#p://www.site.com/pressreleases/another_release.html`
to
`h#p://www.site.com/pressreleases/details.php?id=2`?

Thanks

Comment: If you follow the Markdown syntax, you can make your question more legible for the rest of us.

Answer (score 5):

Compose a `.htaccess` file in the `pressreleases` directory and specify the following:

```
Redirect 301 some_release.html details.php?id=1
```

If you would like to redirect using regular expressions, use [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html) as [explained here](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/301-redirect-with-mod_rewrite-or-redirectmatch.html).

There are various options listed [on this page](http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/web-redirection.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of these URLs, and assuming you have access to the Apache config, consider creating a "redirects.inc" file in /etc/apache2 (or anywhere really) and then adding "include /etc/apache2/redirects.inc" to your virtual host. That way you have one place to add/update your redirects.

Comment: Thanks. Would the include page just be a series of "Redirect 301..." statements then?

Comment: Exactly. You might even be able to autogenerate this file if you have a way mapping old links to new ones.